# What is the maximum length of peptide which considered to be hard for synthesis by the current technology?

Tags: biochemistry, synthesis, solid-state-chemistry, chemical-biology, proteins

I am a molecular biologist and work with recombinant proteins. I am wondering what the cut point, in terms of length, is at which I should produce the peptide using heterologous expression rather than ordering a peptide synthesis service? What is the maximum length which makes it hard to chemically synthesis the peptide? Any ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The protein lysozyme (160 amino acids)  has been synthesized using a flow reactor according to https://www.chemistryworld.com/news/protein-synthesis-revolution-on-way-as-large-peptides-made-in-hours-not-days/4011891.article . The same article suggest 50 amino acids as a cut-off where the traditional solid state synthesis would be infeasible.